# Angular 6 cannot read property "toLowerCase' of undefined in search box with filter

Tags: typescript, search, filter, angular6

I'm trying to get a result of search. i used filter function but I got a error

```
HomeComponent.html:13 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

My components.html

```
 <div class="row">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search" (input)="filter($event.target.value)">
```

Mycomponents.ts

```
filter(keyWord: string) {
if (keyWord === undefined || keyWord.length === 0) {
  this.findAllArticles();
  return;
}
this.article = this.article.filter(article => 
  article.category.toLowerCase().includes(keyWord.toLowerCase()) || article.designation.toLowerCase().includes(keyWord.toLowerCase()) 
);
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Assuming what you have written above reflects your actual code, the `category` or `designation` property of one of your articles is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check in your **this.article** array? In some of article **category** or **designation** is not included so this error is throwing.

You can resolve this error with put the condition

```
if(article.category && article.designation){}
```